# Malware scanners for apache log files

Tags: apache-2.2, security

Are the any malware/security scanners out there, that can analyze apache error and access logs and tell me if I have potential risks on my server or if there is unauthorized access etc. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [apache-scalp](https://code.google.com/p/apache-scalp/), an *Apache log analyzer for security*.

Comment: Scalp uses the  pattern signatures from PHP-IDS.  If you like what scalp does and you are running PHP, you can have it work in real time and block attacks rather than just detecting them.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out rootkit hunter and fail2ban. They will do a lot of what you need. Watching the Apache logs seems a little too narrow for my tastes.